# Verify that Shredded Storage is functioning

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, shredded-storage

Using the following snippet, i can set the file chunk size for Shredded Storage, but how can I verify that it's actually functioning properly?

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication http://sp2013wfe

$webapp.WebService.FileWriteChunkSize = 1048576

$webapp.webservice.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to validate it, you'll need to look at the database tables. That said, Shredded Storage cannot be disabled in SharePoint 2013. You're using it automatically.

Take a look at `dbo.DocStreams` in your Content Database. You'll see files which have >1 modification with multiple entries for the DocId value.

`SELECT * FROM DocStreams (NoLock) ORDER BY DocId`

Note that it isn't recommended to read from the database directly.

Bill Baer also wrote up an article on this topic.

[Introduction to Shredded Storage in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2012/11/12/introduction-to-shredded-storage-in-sharepoint-2013-rtm-update/)